# Конструкция "точно уверен"

Tags: грамотная-речь, плеоназм

Правильно я понимаю, что ***"точно уверен"*** — это плеоназм, но не тавтология?

Я вкладываю в *"точно уверен"* смысл *"уверен на 100%",* то есть более активное и безоговорочное утверждение, чем в просто *"уверен".* Правильно ли это?

Comment: Спасибо, shampar, перед тем как задать свой вопрос, я нашёл тот вопрос, но посчитал его отличным от моего, в чём и убедился теперь. Правда, вопрос действительно интересный, так что вы не зря мне ещё раз про него напомнили. ;)

Comment: Вопрос «Думаю, что точно…- это верно?» обсуждался на сайте в 2013 г. – shampar 2 часа назад

Comment: Да понял я, что не в 1913-м, а в 2013-м. ;) Зря только порядок нарушили.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выражение ***точно уверен*** не является ни плеоназмом, ни тавтологией. См.примеры из Национального корпуса русского языка.

Так что если я и пью на работе, то только тогда, когда я точно уверен, что у меня больше нет записей на этот день.Бобылева Мария. Особенности национальной работы // Труд-7, 2009.12.22

Единственное, в чем точно уверен вице-премьер Жуков: "Россия―не Кувейт и вечно существовать на нефтяные доходы не будет". [Елена Шишкунова. Правительство готовится к жизни без нефти // Известия, 2006.03.21]
Теперь обратимся к словарям.

• абсолютно уверенный

• глубоко уверенный

• необыкновенно уверенный

• необычайно уверенный

• совершенно уверенный

**Словарь русской идиоматики. . Сочетания слов со значением высокой степени. Academic. 2011.**

Как видите, с этим словом возможны разные наречия. Хотя и наречие "точно" не представлено, тем не менее, оно синонимично представленным наречиям, о чем свидетельствуют примеры из Национального корпуса русского языка.

**Наречие при этом слове указывает на степень уверенности.**

Comment: Спасибо, Серж! Это хорошо. Вы согласны со вторым моим абзацем?

Comment: Да, Артем, полностью согласен.

Comment: Я очень рад, спасибо!)

Comment: «точно уверен вице-премьер». ====   Журналистские штампы как примеры? Хорошо. Но, примеры для чего и что объясняющие, не ясно, кроме того, что это — злая ирония по поводу знания о конечности всего на свете, и что «точно уверен» надо бы взять в кавычки.

Comment: Приведите мне источник, где говорится, что ''точно" надо брать в кавычки. Зачем? Сможете объяснить?

Comment: Сначала о примере: он зачем?

Comment: Какой пример - из Национального корпуса?

Comment: Он процитирован.

Comment: Где  процитирован ?

Answer (score 2):

*Точно уверен* — странное словосочетание. Особенно, когда оно вне контекста. Привычная роль слова *точно* в других сочетаниях (точно совпасть; точно в цель; точнее некуда) ему больше подходит.

С другой стороны, будучи **уверенным**, человек может заявлять об имеющейся у него точке зрения — позиции, которую он готов защищать, не сходя со своей точки стояния; и тогда, сказанное себе или другим «**Я уверен, я точно уверен**», может выглядеть вполне убедительно. При условии, что уверенность выражена только от первого лица и базируется не на эмоциях, а на аргументах, чтобы не стать самоуверенностью. Это условие диктуется «математической и геометрической» определённостью слова *точно*.

Фраза *Я точно уверен* равноценна *Я знаю*. Но, поскольку знать того, чего не было, нельзя, как предсказание она абсурдна. Это дополнительное ограничение для её хождения: *я точно уверен, что куплю эту машину* — не проходной случай, но *я точно уверен, что книгу оставил на полке* — проходной.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Всегда рад помочь.

Answer (score 0):

Не зря же в словарях нет "*точно уверенного*". Действительно, странное словосочетание. Я бы сказал, неряшливое.